# Using resource model class to save back-end configuration

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, resource-model, adminform

So I have this custom form in the back-end from which I want to save/load values from my custom table in the database.

I have set that form to use a my custom model - this is from the `system.xml` file in the module:

```
<backend_model>myproductimporter/system_config_backend_customoptions</backend_model>
```

This is the class so far:

```
class MODULE_MyProductImporter_Model_System_Config_Backend_Customoptions extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Serialized
{
    /**
     * Constructs an array of custom options data mapped to and organized by their template ID.
     * Save actual data in custom_options_import_templeates table.
     *
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()
     */
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if (is_array($value)) {
            unset($value['__empty']);
        }

        /* my custom functionality */

        $this->setValue($value);
        parent::_beforeSave();
    }

    protected function _afterLoad() {
        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }
}
```

So the functionality in these 2 functions is the same as in the parent class. Only the `/* my custom functionality /*` does some mapping stuff over the data. *This manipulated data I want to save in my own way in my own table in the DB.*

I have created a Resource model class:

```
class MODULE_MyProductImporter_Model_Resource_Import_Importer extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {

    protected function construct() {
        $this->_init('myproductimporter/import_importer', 'id');
    }

    public function saveCustomOptions(array $valuesToSave) {
         /* process the data given from the function from Customoptions.php
            and save it in my custom table in the DB */
    }
}
```

And I have configured the resource class:

```
<global>
        <models>
            <myproductimporter>
                <class>MODULE_MyProductImporter_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>myproductimporter_resource</resourceModel>
            </myproductimporter>
            <myproductimporter_resource>
                <class>MODULE_MyhProductImporter_Model_Resource_Import_Importer</class>
                <entities>
                    <myproductimporter>
                        <table>custom_options_import_templates</table>
                    </myproductimporter>
                </entities>
            </myproductimporter_resource>
        </models>
```

What I don't understand is the process flow. Where should I call the `saveCustomOptions` function? It seems to me that it should be in the `_beforeSave` but that also doesn't make sense, since this function should finish its job before the *save* is done. I get until the end of `_beforeSave()`, but then I am lost in what should I do...

Also, how is the manipulated-and-ready-to-save data (in `saveCustomOptions()`) processed and saved?

The table where I want to save the data is called `custom_options_import_templates`

Answer (score 1):

So maybe this does not answer your question here is a small insight into how magento deals with this sort of thing:

1. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::_afterSave` - saves the links for product to website and category,
2. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option::_afterSave` - saves price and and translation information for product options,
3. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_beforeSave` - updates path and children count,
4. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_afterSave` - saves product links,
5. `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_beforeSave` - validates a few attributes and sets the created date for new pages,
6. `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_afterSave` - assign pages to stores and invalidate the cache,
7. `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_beforeSave` - validate some attributes,
8. `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_afterSave` - trigger save of address,

So from these few items I would say, with a massive generalisation, that Magento tends to use _before save for validation and setting up some default values and used _after to saving information into linked tables.

I hope this helps you make your choice.